# How to replace libjpeg with libjpeg-turbo when using gstreamer sdk android?

Tags: android, gstreamer, libjpeg-turbo

The project https://github.com/iiordanov/bVNC using gstreamer sdk(http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development).
the jpeg library used by it is jpeglib.
I want to replace jpeglib with libjpeg-turbo to improve mjpeg decoding performance. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**1, I changed the Android.mk file in jni/src. Below is the changed version. I haven't replaced the jpeglib used by gstreamer, but replaced the jpeglib used by aSPICE. The bVNC code I am using is v3.3.5.**

**2, When compiling libjpeg-turbo 1.3.0, make sure you configure it with --with-jpeg8.**

**3, Below is the modified Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LIB_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/armeabi

SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS   := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/deps

CROSS_DIR   := /opt/android

spice_objs := \
                   $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libssl.a \
                   $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libcrypto.a \
           $(CROSS_DIR)/lib/libturbojpeg.a   \
                   $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libcelt051.a 

LOCAL_MODULE    := spice

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := channel-record.c channel-playback.c channel-cursor.c \
                   spice-cmdline.c coroutine_gthread.c spice-util.c \
                   spice-session.c spice-channel.c spice-marshal.c spice-glib-enums.c \
                   common/generated_client_demarshallers.c common/generated_client_demarshallers1.c \
                   common/generated_client_marshallers.c common/generated_client_marshallers1.c \
                   gio-coroutine.c channel-base.c channel-main.c spice-proxy.c bio-gsocket.c glib-compat.c \
                   channel-display.c channel-display-mjpeg.c channel-inputs.c decode-glz.c \
                   decode-jpeg.c decode-zlib.c wocky-http-proxy.c channel-port.c spice-client.c spice-audio.c \
                   common/mem.c common/marshaller.c common/canvas_utils.c common/backtrace.c \
                   common/sw_canvas.c common/pixman_utils.c common/lines.c common/rop3.c common/quic.c \
                   common/lz.c common/region.c common/ssl_verify.c common/log.c spice-gstaudio.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS    += $(spice_objs) \
                   -ljnigraphics -llog -ldl -lstdc++ -lz -lc \
                   -malign-double -malign-loops
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -L$(LIB_PATH) -lgstreamer_android

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  += -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"GSpice\" \
                   -DSW_CANVAS_CACHE \
                   -DSPICE_GTK_LOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" \
                   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -UHAVE_SYS_SHM_H -DSW_CANVAS_CACHE  \
                   -D_REENTRANT -DWITH_GSTAUDIO

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/common \
                    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS    :=  $(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS) \
                   -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wl,--no-undefined \
                   -fPIC -DPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -ffast-math

LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS += $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_LDLIBS)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := spice-android
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := android/android-service.c android/android-spicy.c android/android-spice-widget.c \
                   android/android-io.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := spice
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT
ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif
GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID)
endif
GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS)
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := glib-2.0 gthread-2.0 pixman-1 gstreamer-app-0.10

include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer.mk
```